# JMeter UltimateThreadGroup making my Jenkins pipeline fail

Tags: gradle, jmeter, jenkins-pipeline, pipeline, jmeter-plugins

I have a Jenkinsfile pipeline and in one of its stages I run some jmeter tests and generate the respective report.

This is my stage

```
  stage('Run Non-Functional tests - Windows'){
            when { expression { env.OS == 'BAT' }}
            steps {                
                dir('') {
                    bat 'gradlew.bat jmReport'
                }
            }
        }
```

and this is my build gradle

```
import de.qualersoft.jmeter.gradleplugin.task.*

plugins {
    id "de.qualersoft.jmeter" version "2.1.0"
}

tasks.register('jmRun',JMeterRunTask) {
    jmxFile.set("TestPlan.jmx")
}

tasks.register("jmReport",JMeterReportTask) {
    jmxFile.set("TestPlan.jmx")
    dependsOn("jmRun")
    deleteResults=true
}
```

When I try to run my pipeline it fails with the following error

```
 Error in NonGUIDriver java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Problem loading XML from:'D:\ISEP\Mestrado\UnidadesCurriculares\1Ano\1Semestre\2022_2023\ODSOFT\odsoft-22-23-nmb-g303\src\test\jmeter\TestPlan.jmx'. Cause: CannotResolveClassException: kg.apc.jmeter.threads.UltimateThreadGroup
```

In JMeter, I used the plugin catsug 2.1.0 to do some spike and load tests and I think that's the reason why the exception is thrown.

I tried to use a simple file where the test plan didn't use the plugin and pipeline works fine.

How can I solve my problem?

I added as a dependency but now I am getting another error

```
dependencies {
    jmeterPlugin("kg.apc:jmeter-plugins-casutg:2.10") 
    jmeterPlugin("org.apache.jmeter:bom:5.4.1")
}
```

```
Execution failed for task ':jmRun'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':jmeterPlugin'.
   > Could not find org.apache.jmeter:bom:5.4.1.
     Required by:
         project :
   > Could not find org.apache.jmeter:bom:5.4.1.
     Required by:
         project : > org.apache.jmeter:ApacheJMeter_core:5.4.1
         project : > org.apache.jmeter:ApacheJMeter_core:5.4.1 > org.apache.jmeter:jorphan:5.4.1
```

Answer (score -1):

The error means that the Ultimate Thread Group plugin is not installed, in order to add it you need to [explicitly specify the plugin as the dependency](https://github.com/qualersoft/jmeter-gradle-plugin#adding-plugins) for your project:

```
dependencies {
  jmeterPlugin("kg.apc:jmeter-plugins-casutg:2.10") 
}
```

You might also be interested in [Jenkins Performance Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jenkins-performance-plugin) which allows displaying performance trend charts and conditionally mark build as failed if metrics are worse than in the previous/reference build.

Comment: I added it as a dependency but now I am getting another error ( check the added part of the question). I am using Groovy for my build.gradle

Comment: I'm not going to open this page daily to check if you edited your question with new queries. You have been given the answer, if you have another problem - start another question.

Comment: the error is because of the dependency added